# Integration of time interval for user activity from the database

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

stack overflow
I am new to programming and am working on a donation site in which each user will have 2hours to complete a payment or be removed from the database, how do I set the time out from the database for each user.
Secondly, I am working on 15% ROI, I have done calculation have provided a variable for it called it $gain.
My question now how do I integrate all of this in my database. 
    Please your ultimate response is highly needed and                          appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask]. You are expected to try it yourself - if you have problems with the code you design, ask specific questions about those problems.

Comment: When user starts the transaction, you can enter him in the database with his entry timestamp. Create a middleware(a logic before showing the html response for a url route). When user is reaching towards the final step, between each redirects or server requests if the 2 hours time is over tell the user about it. If use submits  the request, check if its withing the 2 hours window using the entry timestamp. If yes then proceed otherwise redirect user and delete his entry. Also remember to setup  cron to remove all the users who just entered on your website  but never went ahead for a transaction

Comment: @Blastfreak, I want the 2hour timing to be automatic from the database not manually set. Can I use settimeout function in JavaScript, if I can, how do I integrate it to my database to make it automatic